# pandas conditional aggregation

Tags: python, pandas, aggregation

I want to group the below dataframe based on 'id', then have the aggregate sums of 'flow' for all values of 'id' except 0; those should stay independent. What is the best solution?

Original:

```
id  flow
0   1
0   1
1   1
1   1
2   1
2   1
```

Aggregated:

```
id  flow
0   1
0   1
1   2   
2   2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to use `transform` to assign the new flow values back and then drop duplicates:

```
In [48]:

df.loc[df['id'] != 0, 'flow'] = df.groupby('id')['flow'].transform('sum')
df.drop(df[df['id']!=0].drop_duplicates().index)
Out[48]:
   id  flow
0   0     1
1   0     1
3   1     2
5   2     2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could break this up into the problem where you are doing a group by across all ids excluding 0 and then just appending the values for 0. I.e.

```
df = DataFrame({"id":[0,0,1,1,2,2],"flow":[1,1,1,1,1,1]})
df1 = df[df["id"]!=0].groupby('id').sum().reset_index()
pd.concat([df[df['id']==0], df1]).reset_index(drop=True)
```